# Regex to find numbers, hyphen ad commas in a number sequence

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to allow numbers, commas and hyphen in the middle.
I have 2 patterns (x denotes numbers)

1. xx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx
2. xx-xx-xx, xx-xxx

I tried something like this for the 1st pattern
`^[0-9](?:-?[0-9])*$`

I am unable crack the second pattern.
My Regex understanding is not good, some help from the community will be great.

Is there an efficient way to check for both pattern in a single regex.

Thanks
Palani

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with your expected output

Comment: Are you looking for 

^\d+[-\d,?\s]+


https://regex101.com/r/77vmSx/1

Comment: To be more string about your patterns I'd suggest `^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d(?:-\d{3}-\d{3}|, \d\d-\d{3})$`

Comment: @Kmandal, you suggestion worked very well. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^\d(?:[-,\s]*\d)*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/6r7oGU/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-,\s]*                  any character of: '-', ',', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

[Python](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolasktaJEwVZB3dBI19hE19RM19zCUtfA0MhYnSszDahArzg1sSg5Q6NIPS4mRcPeKlpXJ6Y4VismRVNLRV1HAaRd04pLAQgKijLzSjTS1JWqQYK1SgqZxQpliTmZKeqaXKk5xam4VWXmQdX9/w8A):

```
import re
text = '12-34-56-789-0123'
if re.search(r'^\d(?:[-,\s]*\d)*$', text):
    print(f'"{text}" is valid')
else:
    print(f'"{text}" is invalid')
```

Result:

```
"12-34-56-789-0123" is valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^[0-9](?:[-,\ ]{,2}[0-9])*$
```

or this:

```
^[0-9](?:[-,\ ]*[0-9])*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the *EXACT* amount of digits, this regex will do:

```
(\d{2}-){2}\d{2}((-\d{3}){2}|,\s\d{2}-\d{3})
```

See at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AQxbQY/2)

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem, as per your question:

```
^(?:[-,\ ]*\d)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/X7MQ7c/1

Comment: also fits `'---+++3333,,,,,,, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,+++--'` which looks nothing like whats being asked for